# Compile to one picture per pages

Tags: compiling

I would like to compile one document so as that each page becomes one single picture. Is it-possible ?

Comment: You can use the tool `pdftk` to split the pdf file.

Comment: Is this convert PDF to JPEG for example ?

Comment: If you compile to PDF, many PDF viewers are able to export as a series of images.

Comment: @projetmbc: No. But you can write a small script. First `pdftk` and than `convert`

Comment: You can also use `ImageMagick` on the output file to split it to separate pages of pictures.

Comment: `convert` and `pdftk` are so easy to use. Thanks or all !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have obtained a PDF file consisting of pages, you need to convert each page to a PNG (for example) using `convert` command provided by [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

The syntax is as follows:

```
convert -density <number> -alpha <option> "filename.pdf" "filename-%03d.png"
```

Note:

- `<number>` is any positive integer. The larger it is the bigger in size the produced image. It depends on the size you want to get. In my experience, you can choose between 100 to 300 or even more. Please make a trial and error test.
- `<option>` is one of `on` (transparency enabled), `off` (transparency disabled), or `remove` (transparency removed). Actually I only use either `on` or `remove`.
- `%03d` is used to append a zero-leading-3-digit counting number for each image. If three digit is too greedy, you can change to two!
- Quotes can be removed if your `filename` has no spaces.

For example you invoke as follows,

```
convert -density 100 -alpha on "filename.pdf" "filename-%02d.png"
```

For more detailed explanation, see my another related answer [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3156/19356).

Comment: Could you add some common values for `number` please?

Comment: I know that it depends on the size, but don’t know the unit. So `numer=20` could be big, but fairly isn’t ;-) Thats why I asked for common values, or an explantation on how the size is defined be `number` …

Comment: @Tobi: Hopefully [this link](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=21076) makes it more clearer.